# A magical thing?

Tags: riddle

> I come in colours, I fall like raindrops.
> I will vanish if I am too many.
> Climb to the top and you will die.
> Who am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your are

> The **Tetris** blocks

I come in colours, I fall like raindrops.

> Describes the Tetris blocks, thats come in different colors and tend to fall down.

I will vanish if I am too many.

> Stack a full line and it vanishes.

Climb to the top and you will die.

> If the stack of blocks goes to high, you lose.

Comment: Someone buy this man a drink!

Comment: @Prince Deepthinker thank you! As for new puzzles, maybe, maybe not, it's hard to tell when inspiration will strike :). And I'll have a Tripel Karmeliet please.